# Invalid sync error while reading avro file using spark or hive

Tags: hive, avro, spark-avro, avro-tools

I have an avro file which is created using JAVA api, when the writer was writing data in file the program shut down ungracefully due to machine reboot.
Now when I am trying to read this file using spark/hive, it reads some data and then throws following error (org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync!)–

```
INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 1 (count at DataReaderSpark.java:41) failed in 7.420 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync!
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:210)
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anon$1.hasNext(DefaultSource.scala:215)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync!
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.nextRawBlock(DataFileStream.java:293)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:198)
        ... 16 more
```

I believe that the last records is broken and not correct. I just wanted to know **if there’s a way I can read this file without getting the exception/error by skipping the last record.**